# When using Editable ComboBox,I can NOT import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

In QML Doc, there are the following:

Import Statement:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
```

Since: Qt 5.7

> "ComboBox can be made editable." ...

I have latest Qt OpenSource 5.9 installed. But I can not import the `QtQuick.Controls 2.2`, even with the simplest qt quick project created by the project wizard. The following error is print:

> qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.2 is not installed

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
...
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

All codes are generated by Qt Creator 4.3

I work on windows 7.

Comment: Can you check if you have installed QtQuick.Controls 2 or not. You can check this by traversing through the folder where Qt is installed. For example, for me `Qt5.9.0\5.9\mingw53_32\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2` is the folder where `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` components like `ComboBox` are present

Comment: Yes, I found the ComboBox under C:\Qt\Qt5.9.0\5.9\msvc2015_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls.2

Comment: I just found I used the 5.8 kit, sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `QtQuick 2.7` installed, you need to import `QtQuick.Controls 2.0`. The import statement in the documentation is sometimes set to the newest version.
This might happen, e.g. when a new property is introduced in a newer version (see [`acceptableInput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#acceptableInput-prop))

The `ComboBox` per se is available since `Qt5.7` and the corresponding `QtQuick.Controls 2.0`, but some properties have been added in `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` which comes with `Qt5.9`.

Comment: I need the editable ComboBox which added in 5.9, so I installed 5.9 but I still can not use it.

Comment: I just found I actually used the 5.8 kit, sorry.

Comment: The QtQuick.Controls 2.2 editable combobox does not work correctly for me. The accepted() signal is not sent properly every time. If I import version 1.4 instead, it does work properly.

Comment: @Colin: We can't help you without code that reproduces your problem. Consider creating a new question with a minimal, complete and verifiable example that reproduces your problem. It might turn out it is a bug. Then you can report it on https://bugreports.qt.io - providing the same example.

Comment: @derM: I will do that. Thank you.